# DATE() sql not working from php

Tags: php, sql

I'm using this query in phpmyadmin and work perfect

```
UPDATE TABLE SET DETALLE = 'PENDING FOR TODAY' where DATE(FECHA) = DATE(NOW());
```

but if I do the same from PHP

```
$sql= "UPDATE TABLE SET DETALLE = 'PENDING FOR TODAY' 
where DATE(FECHA) = DATE(NOW())
$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die ("error");
```

Is not doing anything, if any problem with DATE() from php?

Comment: whats the error turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL)`;

Answer (score 5):

You missed the `";` at the end of your code line.
Besides you can use `curdate()` instead of `date(now())`:

```
$sql = "UPDATE TABLE 
        SET DETALLE = 'PENDING FOR TODAY' 
        WHERE DATE(FECHA) = CURDATE()";
```

And if you have performance problems you can change it to

```
$sql = "UPDATE TABLE 
        SET DETALLE = 'PENDING FOR TODAY' 
        WHERE FECHA >= CURDATE() AND FECHA < CURDATE() + interval 1 day";
```

which uses the index if you have one on `FECHA`.

And please [don't use mysql_* functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). 
They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). 
Learn about **Prepared Statements** instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for a quick overview how to do it and why it is so important.

Comment: Could be the right answer. just a quick addiction. if you plan on using your SQL in MSSQL, change DATE(NOW()) to just GETDATE().

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I tryied all the alternatives but still not working  
$sql = "UPDATE TABLE
        SET DETALLE = 'PENDING FOR TODAY' 
        WHERE FECHA>= GETDATE() AND FECHA< GETDATE() + interval 1 day";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die ("ERROR"); 

Return allways error, is any other way to debug this? Extrange in MySQL is working perfect and from php is not working

Comment: juergen: I want to see the error too! apache is not shooting any error log message. I'm using Apache 2.4.2 with php 5.4.3

Comment: replace  `mysql_query($sql) or die ("error");` with  `mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());` to see the error.

Comment: Thanks Juergen, I see the error is 'No database selected'... I have this in the beginning $con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOSTNAME,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME); where 
echo DB_NAME; return BASE that is the correct database name

Comment: You have to use that connection when you run the query. Change `mysql_query($sql)` to `mysql_query($sql, $con)`. I am no PHP expert but you seem to mix mysql and mysqli functions.

Comment: You are completely right mysqli_query($con,$sql) work perfect! I didn't knew that different Thanks a lot!